# Как рисовать на объекте QCamera в режиме реального времени?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qt5, pyside2

Данный код рисует линию под видео, мне же надо на видео.

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtMultimediaWidgets import QCameraViewfinder
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtMultimedia import QCamera, QCameraInfo
class form (QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super ().__init__ ()
        self.flag = False
        self.initUI ()

    def initUI(self):
 
        self.labelPixMap=QLabel()
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout ()
        self.setLayout (self.layout)
        self.cameraView = QCameraViewfinder ()
        self.cameraInfo = QCameraInfo.defaultCamera ()
        self.camera = QCamera (self.cameraInfo)
        self.camera.setViewfinder (self.cameraView)
 
        self.layout.addWidget (self.cameraView)
    
        if self.camera.status () != QCamera.UnavailableStatus:
            self.camera.start ()
    def imageCaptured(self,id,previewImage):
        self.image = previewImage

    def paintEvent(self,QPaintEvent):
        painter = QPainter (self)
        pen = QPen ()
        pen.setColor (Qt.green)
        painter.setPen (pen)
        painter.drawLine (100, 100, 300, 100)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication (sys.argv)
    wform = form ()
    wform.resize (400, 300)
    wform.show ()
    sys.exit (app.exec_ ())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так, только где рисовать и какого размера - сделаете самостоятельно.

```
'''
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtMultimediaWidgets import QCameraViewfinder
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtMultimedia import QCamera, QCameraInfo
'''
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class form (QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super ().__init__ ()
        self.flag = False
        self.initUI ()

    def initUI(self):
        self.labelPixMap = QLabel()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()                    # QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.cameraView = QCameraViewfinder()
        self.cameraInfo = QCameraInfo.defaultCamera()
        self.camera = QCamera(self.cameraInfo)
        self.camera.setViewfinder(self.cameraView)
 
        self.pushButton = QPushButton("Click me")      # +
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.func)     # +
 
        self.layout.addWidget(self.cameraView)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.pushButton)         # +
    
        if self.camera.status () != QCamera.UnavailableStatus:
            self.camera.start ()
            
    def imageCaptured(self, id, previewImage):
        self.image = previewImage

    def paintEvent(self,QPaintEvent):
        painter = QPainter (self)
        pen = QPen ()
        pen.setColor (Qt.green)
        painter.setPen (pen)
        painter.drawLine (100, 100, 300, 100)
        
    def func(self):
        #self.flag = True
        size = self.style().pixelMetric(QStyle.PM_SmallIconSize)
        size = 400
        pm = QPixmap(size, size)
        pm.fill(Qt.transparent)
        qp = QPainter(pm)
        pen = QPen(QColor(Qt.red), 4)
        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.drawLine(0, size/2, size, size/2)
        # конец рисования на растровом изображении, это тоже важно!
        qp.end()        
        
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.resize(size, size)
        self.label.setPixmap(pm)
        self.label.show()
        self.update()
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    wform = form()
    wform.resize(400, 300)
    wform.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_ ())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, это сработало, но я не совсем понял почему это сработало?

Comment: @lirmon4ik  если мои ответы добавляют вам новых знаний и навыков, вы также можете отмечать ответы как полезные.

Comment: Еще бы знать где это, я ток галочки ставить научился

Comment: @lirmon4ik в верхнем левом углу ответа. Так а что вам не понятно? Рисуем линию, помещаем в `label`, показываем `label` и обновляем окно.

Comment: label помещается поверх видео?

Comment: @lirmon4ik да, поверх всего.